# How to find a space between elements in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to remove the additional space in the 4th paragraph. It was introduced by the XSLT which I have written.

Given below the XML and XSLT output.

```
<Chapter>
<para>A <emphasis>B</emphasis> <emphasis>C</emphasis> <emphasis>N</emphasis> D</para>
<para>A <emphasis>B</emphasis> <emphasis>C</emphasis> <emphasis>N</emphasis> D</para>
<para>A <emphasis>B</emphasis> <emphasis>C</emphasis> <emphasis>N</emphasis> D</para>
<para>A <emphasis>B</emphasis><emphasis>C</emphasis> <emphasis>N</emphasis> D</para>
</Chapter>
```

Given the XSLT code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="para" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="emphasis">
<b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
<xsl:if test="self::emphasis/following::text()[starts-with(., ' ')] and following-sibling::node()[1][self::emphasis]"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<p>A <b>B</b> <b>C</b> <b>N</b> D</p>
<p>A <b>B</b> <b>C</b> <b>N</b> D</p>
<p>A <b>B</b> <b>C</b> <b>N</b> D</p>
<p>A <b>B</b><b>C</b> <b>N</b> D</p>
```

I know the problem is with the strip-space given in the XSLT, that's why the spaces removed between those elements. I have tried to overcome the stip-space and given space between those elements. Still, there is an additional space that has been added in the 4th paragraph after **B**. Anyone know how to remove that unwanted space or any solution present to give the space between those elements.

Comment: It is not clear which spaces you want to insert and which ones you want to avoid or remove, perhaps add the desired output as well as a verbal description of the input - output transformation in a functional way.

Comment: I have given the strip-space for the paragraph tag in the above XSLT, without removing the strip-space, I need to retain the spaces properly in the output.
I want to find the space between the emphasis element, if the space is present in that place, then I'm adding the same space through the <xsl:if> condition.

Comment: How would the desired output look? Consider to add that to the question as a code snippet.

Comment: The expected output looks updated in the question. Without removing the below line I need that output.

<xsl:strip-space elements="para" />

Comment: So why do you need the `<xsl:strip-space elements="para" />` instead of not using it or ensuring that the space is preserved? It seems like you cause the problem you say you want to fix.

Comment: Want to improve my XSLT knowledge, I want to find the below condition in the XSLT.

</emphasis> <emplasis>

Need to find, closing </emphasis> tag after space and <emphasis> tag.

Is there any XPath present to find the above logic?

Comment: It is not possible to identify from a code snippet in a comment what you are after when talking about spaces, edit your question and show the details there.